# How do I sync my contacts FROM my iPhone 6 8.1.3 TO my macbook pro Yosemite 10.10.1?

Tags: sync, iphone, contacts

I can't seem to get my contacts from my iPhone to my mac or to my iCloud account. my contacts from my mac and iCloud match, but I have way more contacts in my phone. And no matter what I do, I can't seem to get them from my phone to my mac/icloud. quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

8.1.3 no longer allows offline syncing. Instead, you must be connected to the Internet and logged into iCloud to sync contacts. I learned this by troubleshooting similar issue with Apple Care.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer.  Super User's purpose is to build a knowledgebase, so answers should stick to the facts that address the question and avoid opinion.  I removed the commentary so that your answer is focused on the solution.